# error al loguear con usuario con role diferente a admin

Tags: laravel, oauth, passport

Tengo una api rest hecha en laravel 5.6 donde autentico y registro con passport y oauth, hago registro de forma exitosa pero estoy teniendo problemas para iniciar sesion con usuarios que no tengan rol administrador, me dice que no estan autorizados.

En el front no tengo problemas, verifico y si se envian los datos de logueo, email y password, incluso pasan la validacion, el problema es que en mi funcion login:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{   
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ];

    if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        $token = auth()->user()->createToken('TutsForWeb')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

Cuando el usuario tiene un rol diferente a admin la sentencia auth()->attempt($credentials) se vuelve null y pues por eso me da error 401, no entiendo porque, al loguear con un usuario con rol administrador si funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

tengo mis dudas con respecto si es un problema del método **attempt()**, ya que este método lo que hace es solo verificar que los parámetros que le envías sean idénticos a los de la base de datos.. 
Prueba con lo siguiente :

intenta con lo siguiente :

dd( Auth::attempt($credentials) ), y ve si realmente te devuelve un null.. de ser así verifica que los datos que le estas pasando sean realmente los correctos.

---

Mi modelo User :

```
protected $fillable = [
    'nombre','email', 'password','permiso'
];
```

LoginController:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password),$request->_token))
```

inténtalo, ya no se me ocurre nada mas

suerte.

Comment: El metodo no devuelve null, me equivoque transcribiendo, en realidad genera false, como si el usuario no estuviera en la BD, pero si lo esta, cuando le coloco el role admin a ese mismo usuario pues si me da acceso.

Comment: Entiendo...tuve ese problema y lo resolví de esta manera 

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
  
}

le especifico cuales son los parámetros que debe validar, pruebalo y me comentas

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, creeria que es algun tipo de verificacion por parte de passport o oauth porque cree un nuevo usuario con role administrador y luego le puse otro rol y pues ya con el si pude iniciar sesion, pero si lo creo directamente con un rol diferente a admin no lo acepta

Comment: Tu modelo user esta bien ?  yo tengo un sistema con permisos de usuarios y tengo el modelo User :

 protected $fillable = [
        'nombre','email', 'password','permiso'
    ];


 y en el LoginController hago lo siguiente : 
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password),$request->_token))


espero que te sirva.